# How to install an app in the Android SDK emulator

Tags: mobile, android

I am working on android automation testing. I need to install some .apk files in an emulator. So I have a few questions like:

1. Where should I get the .apk file?
2. How do I install the .apk file?

Comment: you should get APKs from your developers , to install APK , just drag it to emulator.

Comment: I don't think the question is related in any way to SQA. This should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ Helping Hands Thank you. But is there any way to get few apk's from any other source?

Comment: Here is your bag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480201/how-do-you-install-an-apk-file-in-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

You can get apk using chrome plugin [APK Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apk-downloader/cgihflhdpokeobcfimliamffejfnmfii?hl=en).
To install apk use ADB command: `adb install path_to_apk_file`

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way to install any app on emulator**:

- Drag and drop your .apk file on your emulator.
- It will install and restart emulator itself

Your app will be ready to use !